# ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead This file is being treated as an ES module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got this error while running this code.

```
let { controllerUser } = require('./router')
```

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Project\first-project\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

Routing in node js using type module in package.json

Answer (score 2):

if you have "type":"module" in package.json,
try using **import {controllerUser} from "./router.js"**

you can't mix es6 modules with commonJs modules